How to handle inheritance with onBackPressedDispatcher?
Let's see, I have launcher Activity as HomeComposeActivity which extends BaseComposeActivity and it extends BaseActivityV2
HomeComposeActivity -> BaseComposeActivity -> BaseActivityV2 -> AppCompatActivity

I've another activity called CartActivity
CartActivity -> BaseComposeActivity -> BaseActivityV2 -> AppCompatActivity

So from HomeComposeActivity, when I click on button, I'm launching CartActivity
  val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, CartActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

I put logs in All 4 activities like this:
 override fun onBackPressed() {
    showLog("HomeComposeActivity - before - onBackPressed")
    super.onBackPressed()
    showLog("HomeComposeActivity - after - onBackPressed")
}

 override fun onBackPressed() {
    showLog("BaseComposeActivity - before - onBackPressed")
    super.onBackPressed()
    showLog("BaseComposeActivity - after - onBackPressed")
}

 override fun onBackPressed() {
    showLog("BaseActivityV2 - before - onBackPressed")
    super.onBackPressed()
    showLog("BaseActivityV2 - after - onBackPressed")
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    showLog("CartActivity - before - onBackPressed")
    super.onBackPressed()
    showLog("CartActivity - after - onBackPressed")
}

Manifest
android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"

build.gradle
compileSdk 34

Logcat, when I pressed back from CartActivity
    CartActivity - before - onBackPressed
BaseComposeActivity - before - onBackPressed
BaseActivityV2 - before - onBackPressed
BaseActivityV2 - after - onBackPressed
BaseComposeActivity - after - onBackPressed
CartActivity - after - onBackPressed

---Also when I pressed back from HomeComposeActivity and App closed.
HomeComposeActivity - before - onBackPressed
BaseComposeActivity - before - onBackPressed
BaseActivityV2 - before - onBackPressed
BaseActivityV2 - after - onBackPressed
BaseComposeActivity - after - onBackPressed
HomeComposeActivity - after - onBackPressed

